# The 6-order Euler sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to calculate the value of the series
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^4}}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{{{k^2}}}} } \right)} \quad\text{and}\quad \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^5}}}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{k}} } \right)} .$$

Comment: see here for the first sum
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650966/evaluate-sum-infty-n-1-frac1n4-using-parsevals-theorem-fourier-ser

Comment: for the second sum we obtain $1/12\,{\frac {12\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}{\it LerchPhi} \left( -1,2,n
 \right) {n}^{2}+{\pi }^{2}{n}^{2}-12\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{{n}^{2
}}}
$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner So you stopped answering?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^5}=\zeta(5)$

Comment: for the last sum we obtain $(-1)^{n+1} \Phi (-1,1,n+1)+\log (2)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, did you realize these are two double sums?

Comment: Once again, may I suggest that you share your attempts at tackling these two sums? I am sure that the users here would be more willing to help you with this problem if you do so. Thanks.

Comment: The inner sum is already complex to me (even if a CAS gives its expression in terms of two $\zeta$ functions).

Comment: I managed to get
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^5}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=-\frac{7\pi^6}{8640}+\frac{31}{16}\zeta(5)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{32}\zeta^2(3)$$
The first sum might not have a closed form though.