# Sum of the following infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question may seem to be too silly as I am not quite in touch with these things since long, for which I apologise in advance.
How should I proceed to calculate the following?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^4$$

Comment: This is a special case of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^{2k}}$ where Bernoulli numbers and powers of $\pi$ are involved.

Comment: If you meant the infinite series: it is not a trivial sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$ I use, for example, Fourier series to do this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650966/evaluate-sum-infty-n-1-frac1n4-using-parsevals-theorem-fourier-ser

Comment: I'd like to propose another duplicate target, and older post (#28329) that has more content and more links.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As you see from the comments,  the problem is not simple since involving for the infinite sum the [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Still worse, for the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac 1{(n+1)^4}=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-1-\frac{1}{6}\psi ^{(3)}(p+2)$$ where appears the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Fortunately, when $p$ is large, we can use asymptotics and get
$$S_p\simeq \left(\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-1\right)-\frac{1}{3 p^3}+\frac{3}{2
   p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$

Use your calculator for $p=5$. The exact result would be $\frac{1051361}{12960000}\approx 0.0811235$ while the above expansion would give $ \frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{3751}{3750}\approx 0.0820566$ ($1.15$% relative error).