# Obtain sum of a sequence from sum of its odd terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I would like to compute the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}
$$
by using the Fourier series of $f(x)=|x|$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$. Coefficients $b_k$ are all $0$ because $f$ is even. Doing the integration stuff, I obtained:
$$
a_0 = \pi
$$
and
$$
 a_k = \frac{2}{k^2}\bigg((-1)^k-1\bigg)
$$
for $k>0$. The Parseval's equality gives:
$$
\frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_k^2+b_k^2)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2dx
$$
which gives
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi^2k^4}(2-2(-1)^k) = \frac{2}{3}\pi^2
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{48}
$$
which basically says:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{96}
$$
any idea how to obtain the sum from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^4} $using Parseval's theorem (Fourier series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650966/evaluate-sum-infty-n-1-frac1n4-using-parsevals-theorem-fourier-ser)

Comment: Uhmm... not really, only partially. I am still interested, how to solve it using the rearrangement of the last line. Also, none of the solutions in the linked post use the function $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: Are you asking why $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\frac{16}{15}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^4}?$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Already found it myself and the answer got it too. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that what you have is that $2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{(2k+1)^4}=\frac {\pi^4}{48}$. Calling $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{k^4}=S$ you have that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{(2k)^4}=\frac 1{16} S$ and finally you have $S-\frac 1{16}S=\frac 12 \frac {\pi^4}{48}$ from which $S=\frac {\pi^4}{90}$

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have

$${\frac{1}{1^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + \frac{1}{5^4} + ... = \frac{\pi^4}{96}}$$

You want to find

$${\frac{1}{1^4} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + ... = ?}$$

in other words, you want to add on

$${\frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{4^4} + ...}$$

Factoring out a ${\frac{1}{2^4}}$ on the above yields

$${\frac{1}{2^4}\left(\frac{1}{1^4} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + ...\right)}$$

So overall, if you call ${S=\frac{1}{1^4} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + ...}$ you have

$${\left(\frac{1}{1^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + \frac{1}{5^4} + ...\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{4^4} + ...\right) = S}$$

$${\Rightarrow \frac{\pi^4}{96} + \frac{1}{2^4}S = S}$$

Can you now rearrange for ${S}$?