# What is wrong with this definition of Fourier coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

something is wrong with what I am doing.
I'm either:

- Using the wrong definition of something(but from Wikipedia, I don't think I am).
- Did some mistake in my calculations (also don't think so)

So I was trying to do this: [Evaluate $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^4} $using Parseval's theorem (Fourier series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650966/evaluate-sum-infty-n-1-frac1n4-using-parsevals-theorem-fourier-ser)

What I started doing:

$$a_0= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2dx= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} x^2\,dx =\frac{2 \pi^2}{3}$$ here it is already **different** from that topic. But from wikipedia and from my classes this is what I am supposed to be calculating.
I suppose I'm doing something wrong in the definition of the parseval identity. Using my definition of $a_0$ am I suppose to sum $a_0^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$, $\frac{a_0^2}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ or $\frac{a_0^2}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ ?

For clarification I define:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$ whenever $f$ is defined in $[-\pi,\pi]$

My fourier series is then written as:
$$f=\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$$

I know that in this specific case $b_n$ is zero.

So what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: just for the sake of completeness my $a_n$ was also off by a factor of 2, it was $a_n= \frac{4 (-1)^n}{n^2}$

Comment: With your definition: $a_0^2/4$.

Comment: And the factor of $2 \pi$ in the parseval identity remains the same?

Comment: Still my $a_n$ is also off by a factor of 2, so I have to sum $\frac{a_0^2}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2  $  right?

Comment: Sorry, should have been $a_0^2/2$ probably. But that depends on what you want to have on the other side. Let's look at simple things. For $f(x) = \cos x$ we want (and get, if we make no mistake) $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = 0$ for $n \neq 1$. So on the sum side of Parseval, we probably want to have $1^2 = 1$ (after eliminating zeros). On the integral side we get $1$ with $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2 x\,dx$. Now take $f(x) = 1$. On the integral side we get $2$, on the sum side we thus need $a_0^2/2$.

Comment: So my parseval identity is $ \frac{a_0^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2+b_n^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)^{2} dx$ I think!

Comment: No, $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)^2\,dx$.

Comment: Dang, I overlooked the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the sum. Either $$\frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 + b_n^2) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)^2\,dx\,,$$ or (really, just multiply it with $\frac{1}{2}$) $$\frac{a_0^2}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 + b_n^2) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)^2\,dx\,.$$ And that is why the complex Fourier series is infinitely better than the abominable real version.

Comment: Don't worry, I realized the right version with your help :P Thank you